# Yii2 - Saving fixed data in a second table, when create new object

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables „projects“ and „tasks“. They are related with each other.
At creation of a new project, I want to create and save also three related tasks (with some fixed prefiled info), when I save the model.

In the table "tasks" i just want to save the relation to the created project and "task_description", which is predefined.

I am lost here and hope someone can help me. If you need something else, let me know.

THE CONTROLLER
***Projectscontroller.php***

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Projects();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } elseif (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
            'model' => $model
    ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

THE MODEL ***Projects.php***

```
public function getTasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tasks::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: you never added the form that you are submitting, how are you populating the fields for 2 models are you using `FormModel` or `ActiveRecord` apparently it looks you are just passing the `Projects` model to the view.

Comment: thx for your comment. yes was just passing it. didnt get a way to think how to solve the problem so i posted the code without changes i tried to solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Projects();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $taskmodel=new YourTaskModel();
        $taskmodel->project_id=$model->id;    // will get inserted project id
        $taskmodel->task_description='whateverdescription';
        $taskmodel->save();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } elseif (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Basically you are saving the task after project is saved in DB.

Comment: Thx @jmsds. This one was completely perfect. So simple and i didnt get it.

Comment: This quickly gets you into trouble if you create a project from somewhere else in your application.

Comment: I have only two entrance points to create a project. Both refer to the same action "create" in projectscontroller. Again i didnt get it. What will cause the trouble? I think you mean, when i create a project not using this action? So i will have to reuse the code in another action to avoid problems? Sorry for not so smart questions, but still a bit new to Yii and php and so on.

Comment: @Magpie. Glad you were able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the tasks in your project's afterSave method:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if ($insert) {
        // create your tasks
    }
    return parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}
```